# JSDoc/ESLint Reporting "Unresolved variable or type" in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint, jsdoc

I'm encountering an odd issue with some ESLint reporting in a JavaScript file. I added some JSDoc definitions like the following:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} CustomRefA
 * @property {string} attr1
 * @property {string} attr2
 * @property {Boolean} attr3
 * @property {number} attr4
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} CustomRefB
 * @property {string} attr5
 * @property {string} attr6
 * @property {Boolean} attr7
 * @property {CustomRefA} attr8
 */
```

These definitions also get used for declaring return values from functions like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {Object} params
 * @param {string} params.attrA
 * @param {string} params.attrB
 * @returns {CustomRefA}
 */
function doesSomeActionA(options) {
    return { };
}

/**
 *
 * @param {Object} params
 * @param {string} params.attrA
 * @param {CustomRefA} params.attrB
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function doesSomeActionB(params) {
    return { };
}
```

What I can't quite figure out, though, is why when **CustomRefA** is referenced ESLint reports back with:

> Unresolved variable or type 'CustomRefA'

This is also causing references to attributes of any objects assigned with the custom types to be reported back as unresolved, too. This doesn't seem to happen all the time, and I haven't been able find any info to indicate any differences between projects that could explain the issue.

For reference this is in WebStorm 2021.2, with what appears to be ESLint version 7.32.0 (according to Node/NPM). And I have done quite a bit of searching on this, but haven't been able to find much in the way of results that sufficiently applied to the situation.

Comment: Does it work in the same way for you in the 2021.2.2 version of WebStorm?

Comment: works fine for me using similar code. Please check if invalidating caches helps: go to **File | Invalidate Caches...** in the main menu and click on **Invalidate and Restart**

Comment: @s0xzwasd all that managed to do was somehow turn off linting for the file. I've had this happen before, and it requires deleting the file, deleting the .idea folder, reopening the project, and then recreating the file.

Comment: @lena yeah, I've already done that a couple times for various reasons, and it never resolved this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a scratchpad?  I was having this exact issue, and still can reproduce it in a sandbox, but if i move the code over to a file in the project directory the "Unresolved variable or type 'CustomRefA'" message goes away and the file doesn't report any problems.